# Forwarding port 22 on ZTE-ZXHN H1008N

Tags: ssh, port, ssh-tunnel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UP9dr.png)

I don't understand a single thing in regards to networking. I managed to SSH to my other PC on LAN, but I can't seem to figure out how to open up port 22 in order to be able to do that while I am away. No relevant documentation available for this model.. Anyone willing to walk me through this or at the very least point me in the right direction from where I can learn the basics.

Comment: http://screenshots.portforward.com/routers/ZTE/ZXHN_H108N/default.htm

Comment: http://screenshots.portforward.com/routers/ZTE/ZXHN_H108N/Port_Forwarding.htm

Comment: Port 22 also seems blocked by some ISPs. I might pick another port (e.g. 23 or 24) to forward (at least for public, incoming requests, no matter how its is mapped internally).

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable it.
2. Give it a name.
3. Protocol is TCP.
4. I dont think you have to specify wan address.
5. Select some PVC option (PVC1 if available)
6. Here you will select the port range. Since you only want 22 for ssh, put 22 for both, start and end.
7. Lan ip address is the same you used for ssh over LAN, most likely starting with 192.168.1.* (you can get it with ipconfig command in cmd)
8. Lan start and end ports are also 22.

Then use your public ip address or url when connecting.